# How to Change Lock Screen Image from Windows Phone 8 Application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, lockscreen

In referencing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206968(v=vs.105).aspx , I am trying to change the lock screen background from an application. One of the first steps states that you must modify the WMAppManifest file with the following code

```
<Extensions>
  <Extension ExtensionName="LockScreen_Background" ConsumerID="{111DFF24-AA15-4A96-8006-2BFF8122084F}" TaskID="_default" />
</Extensions>
```

I am confused about the `ConsumerID` and `TaskID` criteria. I'm assuming both of these already exist within the application somewhere, or are defaults. Where do I go to access these and set them accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use these values as-is. They are not unique per app.